# UITableView section when previous section is out of screen iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone application and have some trouble with checking the section of a grouped tableview. When the first section is not visible anymore because I scrolled the tableview down and the tableview bounces back, the second section get the settings from the first section? I check which section it is with the indexPath.section value. How can I solve this? Sorry if my english is not correct!

Sorry for the missing code!
Here is a piece of the cellForRowAtIndexPath code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        pinSwitch.hidden = YES;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_item.png"];
    if([headarray count] != 0){
        if(indexPath.row > [headarray count] - 1){
            cell.imageView.alpha = 0;
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Add new",indexPath.row + 1];

        }
        else{
            cell.imageView.alpha = 1;
            NSArray *infoarray = [headarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [infoarray objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
    else if(indexPath.section == 1){


    if(indexPath.row == 0){
//some more cell data
}
```

I think this should be enough to show my problem!

Comment: Your question is a bit diffuse..provide some code and explain what kind of checking are you trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, if you could show us your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` we should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

paste code for cell generation, seems you are not correctly use reuse cell mechanism

EDIT:
code is not full, i think you should do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        pinSwitch.hidden = YES;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_item.png"];
    if([headarray count] != 0){
        if(indexPath.row > [headarray count] - 1){
            cell.imageView.alpha = 0;
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Add new",indexPath.row + 1];

        }
        else{
            cell.imageView.alpha = 1;
            NSArray *infoarray = [headarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [infoarray objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
    else if(indexPath.section == 1){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
  // you should fill cell data for all cases !!!!  
  }
} else { // for example
            cell.imageView.alpha = 1;
            NSArray *infoarray = [headarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = [infoarray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: yes I did that! sorry for the misunderstanding! I filled all the cell data! but if the first section isn't visible, the cells of the second section get some cell data of the first